# How to output the result of a PowerShell cmdlet run in R(system2) as a dataframe

Tags: r, powershell

I'm trying to run some PS cmdlets in R with system2 but I cannot find a way of outputting the result into an R data frame.

Example:

```
PSCommand_ConnectToMSOL <- "Connect-MsolService"
PSCommand_GetAllLicensingPlans <- "Get-MsolAccountSku | ft SkuPartNumber, ActiveUnits, ConsumedUnits"
PS_output <- system2("powershell", args = PSCommand_ConnectToMSOL, PSCommand_GetAllLicensingPlans)
PS_output
```

The result in PowerShell is:
[image]

However in R studio I don't see a result:
[image]

How can I output the results to a data frame?

Comment: Hi, please review my answer below and let me know if it works, as I cannot run your code because I do not have the `Get-MsolAccountSku` Cmdlet.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo/incorrect syntax in your code. Per the [`system2`](http://127.0.0.1:25435/library/base/html/system2.html) documentation, the `args` argument takes in a character **vector** (i.e. `character()`):

[image: args]

Change:

```
PS_output <- system2("powershell", args = PSCommand_ConnectToMSOL, PSCommand_GetAllLicensingPlans)
```

to

```
PS_output <- system2("powershell", args = c(PSCommand_ConnectToMSOL, PSCommand_GetAllLicensingPlans))
```

---

With the original code you posted the `PSCommand_GetAllLicensingPlans` variable would be passed onto the `stdout` `system2` argument which wouldn't make any sense..

Maybe try examining your code just a smidge more before looking for outside help next time!

---

Comment: Hi, I tried a number of possible syntax combinations before posting. The first was to separately using system2 (first, Connect-MSolService and then Get-MsolAccountSku): Error: Get-MsolAccountSku : You must call the Connect-MsolService cmdlet before calling any other cmdlets. Then I joined them with the syntax you proposed: Error: Connect-MsolService : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Get-MsolAccountSku'. So I tried without the c() wrapping, and I got no errors, but also no result. Not sure what to try next...

Comment: Just try running it with the entire string in system2, system, and if neither work then use the shell.exec function

Comment: Meaning don't use args just run system2("pwsh -noprofile cmd -arg -arg") - also make sure you don't need to import a module

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the "`stdout = TRUE`" option with the system32 command, which returns the output to R, which can then be stored in an R variable.  For example:

```
PS_output <- system2("powershell", args = c(PSCommand_ConnectToMSOL, PSCommand_GetAllLicensingPlans), stdout = TRUE)
```